# How can you serialize an XMP XML block to an existing JPEG Image?

Tags: java, xml, jpeg, xmp

I have many JPEG images which contain corrupted XMP XML blocks.  I can easily fix these blocks but I'm unsure how to write the 'fixed' data back to the image files.

I'm currently using JAVA but am open to anything that will make this task easy.

This is the goal for [another question around XMP XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961629/how-do-you-trim-the-xmp-xml-contained-within-a-jpg) asked earlier.

Comment: after some digging around on stackoverflow I ran across this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838829/library-for-writing-xmp-to-a-multipage-tiff which is basically the same question.  I'm investigating now on whether the answer will really work for what I need or not.  If it does I'll post back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JAVA you can use the [Apache Sanselan library](http://commons.apache.org/imaging/):

```
String newXmpXmlString = "<the><new/><xmp/><xml/></the>";
File file = new File('path/to/file');
new JpegXmpRewriter().updateXmpXml(new ByteSourceFile(file), new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)), newXmpXmlString);
```

For a more detailed example of the solution outlined above there is an open source project on Google Code that houses a small [jPeg XMP XML Trimmer](https://code.google.com/p/jpegxmpxmltrimmer/).